# Storing a list of values from mysql query results

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using a stored procedure I need to store a list of values returned from mysql query to use later.

```
DECLARE dt_list varchar(200) DEFAULT '';
SET @dt_list = '';
select distinct @dt_list = d.data_type_id from db.types as d inner join db.classes as c on c.clid=d.dt_class where d.dt_class=100;
Select @dt_list;
select stuff from db.table where class in (@dt_list)
```

`@dt_list` returns nothing.  What I would like is a list `1,2,3,4,5`

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of MySQL variables: local variables you `DECLARE`, which have no `@` sigil, and user-defined session variables which do have the `@` sigil. These are different variables, even when the name appears to be spelled the same other than the sigil, and you cannot mix them.

Except when used in the `SET` command, the `=` operator is for equality comparison, not assignment. You may use `:=` as an assignment operator in a select-list, but I would recommend using `SELECT ... INTO` instead to make your queries more clear.

To put a comma-separated list into a scalar variable, you first need to turn it into a string. The `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function can do this.

You cannot use a string of comma-separated values as the argument to the `IN()` predicate. What you get is a comparison to the single string, not to the discrete values that appear to make the list. You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` instead.

So here's what I would expect to see for your example:

```
DECLARE dt_list varchar(200) DEFAULT '';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT d.data_type_id) INTO dt_list
FROM db.types AS d INNER JOIN db.classes AS c ON c.clid=d.dt_class 
WHERE d.dt_class=100;

SELECT dt_list;

SELECT stuff FROM db.table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(class, dt_list) > 0;
```